# Croogo and CakePHP - PHP code showing up in HTML source

Tags: php, cakephp

I am running a wamp server and I installed croogo, then when I replaced the app folder with a site I am developing for a client I started to see the php code showing up in parts of the html. Everything worked fine until I replaced the app folder.

You can view the code here http://lytroo-tmp.dyndns.org/croogo5/users/login, I am not sure why it is reacting the way that it is.  Only small parts of the php source is outputting in the html, but it caused errors throughout the whole site because the code is not running.

**EDIT**
Seems that is issue is just in the .ctp files. If the php tag does not contain '' and is just '' it outputs as html.  How would you solve this?

let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like part of the PHP is being read as text so you should go through the code and make sure that you've correctly opened the php code segment:

```
<?php 
     echo 'other code';
     sessionFlash(); 
?>
```

Comment: Or find an option "short_open_tag" in your php.ini and turn on his

Comment: See my edit above. It seems to be an issue with the .ctp files.